# Getting '-[__NSArrayM city]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x111c03460' error

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I'm trying to use Google's geocoding api to get the city name and geolocation. But I'm getting this error and don't know which part I go wrong. Could anyone please help?

Here's my code:

ViewController:

```
- (void)searchCityGeoLocationByName:(NSString *)name
{
    [self.searchResults removeAllObjects];
    NSString *requestUrl = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%@&sensor=true&key=%@", name, GOOGLE_GEOCODING_API_KEY] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager GET:requestUrl
      parameters:nil
         success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
             [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
             NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)operation.response;
             if (httpResponse.statusCode == 200) {
                 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                     NSMutableArray *results = [NSMutableArray array];

                     for (id response in [responseObject objectForKey:@"results"]) {
                         self.search = [[Search alloc] initWithDictionary:response];
                         [results addObject:self.search];
                     }
                     self.searchResults = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:results.count];
                     for (int i = 0; i < results.count; i++) {
                         [self.searchResults addObject:results];
                     }

                     [self.searchController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
                 });
             }

         } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
             NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
         }];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SearchCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    Search *search = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = search.city;

    return cell;
}
```

Search.h:

```
@interface Search : NSDictionary

- (id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)otherDictionary;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *city;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *lat;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *lng;

@end
```

Search.m:

```
- (id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)otherDictionary
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.city = [otherDictionary objectForKey:@"formatted_address"];
        self.lat = [[otherDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"geometry.location"] objectForKey:@"lat"];
        self.lng = [[otherDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"geometry.location"] objectForKey:@"lng"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: NSArray does not have a method called `city`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < results.count; i++) {
    [self.searchResults addObject:results];
}
```

to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < results.count; i++) {
    [self.searchResults addObject:results[i]];
}
```

you adding array to self.searchResults and try to get Search object.

Comment: Thank you, that solves the problem! I didn't realize that I was adding the array rather than the object into the NSMutableArray.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
self.searchResults = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:results.count];
for (int i = 0; i < results.count; i++) {
    [self.searchResults addObject:results];
}
```

With:

```
self.searchResults = results;
```

You can also just remove the results variable and use directly the self.searchResults variable instead.

Answer (score 0):

When you are adding objects to `self.searchResults` you are adding the `NSMutableArray` `results` each time, so then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` when you try to assign `search` to:

```
Search *search = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Instead you are returning an NSMutableArray, so on the next line, when you try to access the `search.city` the object is an array, rather than a `Search` object.

You need to look at whether these lines are correct:

```
for (int i = 0; i < results.count; i++) {
    [self.searchResults addObject:results];
}
```

Are you sure you want to be adding `results` there? Is an `NSMutableArray` of `NSMutableArrays` what you want `self.searchResults` to contain?

You probably want to replace it with something like this:

```
[self.searchResults addObject:results[i]];
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! @Greg's solution does work and solve my issue. I didn't realize that I was adding the array but not the object into the self.searchResults. But your answer did help me get clearer on this issue. Thanks!